# How do I convert every two value of array into its own array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array which structure `[a, [b], c, [d], ...]`, for example:

```
array = [0, [1], 2, [1]]
```

And I need:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 1]]
```

How do I do it? :P

Update:

I was wondering how wil handle this array

```
array = [0, [], 1, [], 2, []]
```

into

```
[[0, 1], [2, 1]]
```

That is remove the empty ones and merge as shown above accordingly.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write:

```
array.each_slice(2).map { |x, ys| [x, ys.first] }
#=> [[0, 1], [2, 1]]
```

Note that you can also write `map { |x, (y)| [x, y] }` though it's certainly a cryptic unpacking.

Comment: Hello there, can you help me with the updated question/section above? .Thank you :)

Comment: actually its ok. i got it. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
array.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
```

Comment: Hello there, can you help me with the updated question/section above? .Thank you :)

Comment: actually its ok. i got it.